# How to factorize the quadratic $a(b-c)x^2 + b(c-a)x + c(b-a) = 0$?

Tags: quadratics, factoring

How do i factorize this equation:
$a(b-c)x^2 + b(c-a)x + c(b-a) = 0$

I tried the quadratic formula, but the discriminant is not factorising into a perfect square. 
Please help!

Comment: You are not guaranteed that the discriminant is a perfect square.  If not, you may have to leave the square root there, but you will get a pair of factors.

Comment: the discriminant is a perfect square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Observe  that $$a(b-c)-c(b-a)=-b(c-a)$$

Put the value of $b(c-a),$ and take out common from the first two terms & the last two terms and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

When $a=1,b=2,c=3$ you obtain $-x^2+4x+3$, whose discriminant is $28$, a nonsquare.
When $a=1,b=2,c=1$ you obtain $x^2+1$, whose discriminant is $-1$.

Conclusion : the discriminant is not a perfect square in general, it may be positive or negative. There is no factorisation (unless there is a typo in the OP).